# Test Automatic Connectivity

Tags: 11.04, wireless, network-manager

I tried Test Automatic Connectivity on 11.04 beta 2 and as I try to follow these instructions:

Using Unity

1. Ensure that NetworkManager is running (computer icon in the notification area) and that no networks are currently connected.
2. Click on Ubuntu Logo and search Terminal.
3. **In the terminal, run ifconfig. Verify that only the loopback device ("lo") is listed.**
4. Right-click on the NetworkManager icon and ensure that Enable Wireless is checked.
5. After approximately 30 seconds, left-click on the NetworkManager icon. Verify that one or more wireless networks are visible.
6. Select an open (no "shield" symbol next to it) network and left-click it. Verify that the network connection succeeds and that a series of bars replaces the NetworkManager icon.
7. In the terminal, run `ifconfig`. Verify that a new network interface is listed.
8. In the terminal, run `route -n`. Note the IP address that is not "0.0.0.0" in the Gateway column.
9. In the terminal, run `ping -c 5 [gateway]` where `[gateway]` is the IP address of the Gateway, above. Verify that the command reports "5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received".

In my case It is not only loopback listed:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:38:b4:3e:a3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4496 (4.4 KB)  TX bytes:4496 (4.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:9e:8e:c8:46  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:9eff:fe8e:c846/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:759864 (759.8 KB)  TX bytes:186146 (186.1 KB)
```

The same thing with Verify Release of Device test. In instruction it's written to get just "lo" in terminal, but I get also eth0:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:38:b4:3e:a3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:44 Base address:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4496 (4.4 KB)  TX bytes:4496 (4.4 KB)
```

In instruction it is written, that it should be only loopback. I obviously have more than just "lo". What's the deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `ifconfig` lists every networking device it finds. So usually the `lo`-device exists on every computer and you will at least see this. However many computers have a networking card and this is configured at system start. So you see two devices in that case. The name `eth0` means ethernet card number 0.

The description above now activates your wireless card. So you see a device called `wlan0`. On some computers (or with some wireless cards) this name can also be like `eth1` or so. The command `ifconfig` shows you that there are now two (eth0, lo) or three (eth0, wlan0, lo) configured interfaces. Your computer transferred some bytes (see `RX bytes` and `TX bytes`) with your wireless card.

However the command `ifconfig` lists *every* networking device it is aware of. So in your case it seems quite natural that it shows also the networking card which is probably built into your computer.